# displaying pdf files located in temp folder using IFrame

Tags: php

Well, I got an API which read binary file from database and store it as "PDF" in windows temp folder, then it sends the path to that file to "PHP" page. What I want is to display that file over the browser.

The API returns the PDF file path: `C:\Users\username\APPDATA\Local\Temp\some file.pdf`. What I have done is setting that path to an `iframe` in my page,
but it shows nothing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: So your Windows server generates a file under `C:\Users\username\APPDATA\Local\Temp\some file.pdf`- how should the user who sees the web page access this directory. The user is on the client side and the pdf is on the server side. You need to use a link that the webserver can access, e.g. copy the file to `<webserverDocRoot>/tmp/some file.pdf` and then create a link to `/tmp/some file.pdf`.

Comment: i feel ashamed that i missed that, my API is now building the PDF file withing my PHP project files, and set the IFrame source to the file path,
but i don't want those generated pdf files to stay withing my folders after the client saw them any way to delete the pdf file let's say after 1 minute??
sorry for my language :)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert that local path to an url one.

`Http://www.yourpage.com/folder_where_you_keep_those_files/file.pdf`

And give the proper folder and file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF is on YOUR computer, the user cannot access YOUR C:\ drive.

You cannot exchange your client-side files with someone server-side.

Store your PDF file on the server somewhere and set that path in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move that file from you local path (it can be your tmp folder or another folder that is not in your web accessible path) to your web directory so that you can put that in your iframe source.

Eg:

```
<iframe src="http://yourwebsite.com/somepdf.pdf" width="1000px" height="800px" >
```